# Not able to run shell script on windows machine using git bash tool

Tags: shell, cross-platform

Getting following error on running shell script file on windows machine :
./ABC_token.sh: line 33: json: command not found
Authentication failed!

Command used: sh  ./ABC_token.sh -u "username” -p “password"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your script `ABC_token.sh` calls the command/function called `json` from its 33rd line (this is what the error message tells you).

I am not aware of the `json` command in standard GitBash distribution (or typical Linux distros), so I am going to assume that it's either a shell function that has been previously defined elsewhere, or it's a command that is provided by some other package. One last possibility is that there are extra line breaks in your script, and line 33 should in fact be a continuation of the previous line.

If you provide more details on where the `ABC_token.sh` comes from, and what it does, maybe we can figure out how to solve or work around your problem.